# How To Draw Polylines in Google Maps With Longitudes And Latitudes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Javascript and the `Google Maps API`. I'm trying to draw a Polyline layer of across specific roads. I can easily get the Longitude and Latitudinal coordinate.

Does anyone know how to go about this? Tutorials will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://openlayers.org/ a javascript lib for this

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already found an example here http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_overlays_polyline